# Access to count records prior to current record

Tags: ms-access

Consider the Access records below:

```
> Name   |  Year  |
> Joe    | 2011   |
> Joe    | 2012   |
> Ann    | 2012   |
> Joe    | 2013   |
> Ann    | 2013   |
```

I would like to calculate the running count of year per name per record, so as to get:

```
> Name   |  Year  | Prior Year Count |
> Joe    | 2011   | 0                |
> Joe    | 2012   | 1                |
> Ann    | 2012   | 0                |
> Joe    | 2013   | 2                |
> Ann    | 2013   | 1                |
```

I don't know what to use to get this result. Please help.

Comment: You are looking for some sort of row number functionality, which Access doesn't support.  But even if it did, you need to have some way of specifying an order to your result set.  I mean that you need to be able use `ORDER BY` along with some set of columns to get the output you showed us.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following @Aleksandar Matic's answer I proceeded to link my table with a copy of that table, linked by the customer_id. Then in the where clause I asked that the years of the copy to be counted should be inferior or equal to the year of the current row of the table. Also I asked for that year to be after 1999.

The code is:

```
SELECT my_table.customer_id, my_table.year, Count(my_table_copy.year) AS year_count
FROM my_table LEFT JOIN my_table AS my_table_copy ON my_table.customer_id = my_table_copy.customer_id
WHERE (((my_table_copy.year)<=[my_table].[year] And (my_table_copy.year)>"1999"))
GROUP BY my_table.customer_id, my_table.year;
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using this SQL query to get your results, just change the name of your table and columns if needed

```
select [Name], [Year], (select count(*)
                        from your_table yt_sq
                        where yt_sq.Name = yt.Name and yt_sq.Year < yt.Year)
from your_table yt
```

Comment: Okay I get it. Let me translate that in SQL for Access and see if I succeed.

Comment: I used the design view and the SQL equivalent is: `SELECT my_table.customer_id, my_table.year, Count(my_table_copy.year) AS year_count
FROM my_table LEFT JOIN my_table AS my_table_copy ON my_table.customer_id = my_table_copy.customer_id
WHERE (((my_table_copy.year)<=[my_table].[year] And (my_table_copy.year)>"1999"))
GROUP BY my_table.customer_id, my_table.year;
`
this is a bit different than what you suggested but put me on the right track.